# how to set main class in SBT 0.13 project

Tags: scala, sbt

Could you guys please explain to me how to set main class in SBT project ? I'm trying to use version 0.13.

My directory structure is very simple (unlike SBT's documentation). In the root folder I have `build.sbt` with following content

```
name := "sbt_test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1-local"

autoScalaLibrary := false

scalaHome := Some(file("/Program Files (x86)/scala/"))

mainClass := Some("Hi")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0.M5b" % "test"
)

EclipseKeys.withSource := true
```

And I have subfolder `project` with single file `Hi.scala` which contains following code

```
object Hi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!")
}
```

I'm able to compile it by calling `sbt compile` but `sbt run` returns

```
The system cannot find the file C:\work\externals\sbt\bin\sbtconfig.txt.
[info] Loading project definition from C:\work\test_projects\sbt_test\project
[info] Set current project to sbt_test (in build file:/C:/work/test_projects/sbt_test/)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 8, 2013 6:14:41 PM
```

Comment: Your experience is not typical. Have you considered whether your non-standard Scala build might be part of the problem?

Comment: @RandallSchulz Nope. Because I can compile. Also for the sake of experiment I changed setting to let SBT get Scala compiler and renamed name of the class in `mainClass`. `sbt run` worked anyway :) Which indicates that SBT simply ignores the setting.

Comment: Why do you use SBT 0.13 (only milestone available) instead of the latest release 0.12.3? Why don't you use the default directory structure (sources go into `src/main/scala`)? Why don't you use a default Scala version?

Comment: @HeikoSeeberger I took whatever was latest on SBT's website. Directory structure of standard Play Framework project is different. I wanted to force Play to use latest version of scala instead of forcing to 2.9.2. Could you please upvote the question ?

Comment: You are missing some important points: First, http://www.scala-sbt.org shows 0.12.3 as the latest (released) version. Second, the Scala version sbt is using internally is not related to the Scala version for your project, except that it is used as a default if you don't set a different `scalaVersion` in your build. Third, Play, like many other Scala libraries, is compiled against a specific version of Scala and you must use that (or a binary compatible upgrade). Fourth, I'm exclusively acting on my own behalf here.

Comment: @HeikoSeeberger Issues described in this question were not related to alpha version. But nice try.

Comment: project directory contains build definition, not your project classes, as explained at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to put your application's source in `src/main/scala/`, `project/` is for build definition code.

Comment: Didn't help. Moreover I can't even compile now. Get Java exception  http://pastebin.com/MUbRQfvx

Comment: different problem, remove `autoScalaLibrary := false` & `scalaHome := Some(file("/Program Files (x86)/scala/"))` lines and set `scalaVersion := "2.10.1"`

Comment: You're right. Exception was caused by `autoScalaLibrary`. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Try to use an object and extend it from App instead of using class

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello from main scala object")
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is how to specify main class

`mainClass in (Compile,run) := Some("my.fully.qualified.MainClassName")`

Comment: Actually `mainClass := Some("Hi")` would also be fine, because sbt will fall back to more general scopes if there is no value for a key in a more specific scope.

Comment: @HeikoSeeberger `mainClass := Some("Hi")` doesn't work in 0.12.3 if my project have two classes with `main` method. SBT asks me to select the class.

Comment: If you're using scala, it also expects the `Main` that `extends App` to be an `object`. I was really dumb and this hung me for a bit.

Comment: I also have multiple main classes, runnable applications, in my project but I repeatedly run just one for long periods of time, preselecting is very useful. I put this to my buid.sbt file:

mainClass in (Compile,run) := Some("my.home.z033.rngtest.RngTest1")
..and it worked perfectly.

Shortened variant of:
mainClass := Some("my.home.z033.rngtest.RngTest1")
did not work for me (sbt 0.13.1)

Answer (score 6):

For custom modules in SBT (0.13), just enter on the SBT console:

```
 project moduleX
 [info] Set current project to moduleX (in build file:/path/to/Projects/)
 >   run
 [info] Running main
```

to switch scope to moduleX, as define in Built.scala. All main classes within that scope will be detected automatically. Otherwise you get the same error of no main class detected. 
For God's sake, SBT does not tell you that the default scope is not set. It has nothing to do with default versus non default source folders but only with SBT not telling anything that it doesn't know which module to use by default.

**Big Hint to typesafe**: PLEASE add a default output like:

```
[info] Project module is not set. Please use ''project moduleX''  set scope 
or set in Built file (LinkToDocu)
```

at the end of SBT start to lower the level of frustration while using SBT on multi module projects.....

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue: was mode following the tutorial at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html, and in my opinion, as a build tool `sbt`'s interaction and error messages can be quite misleading to a newcomer.

It turned out, hours of head scratching later, that I missed the critical `cd hello` line in the example each time. :-(

Comment: Conny, you can just ask me :) I sit infront of you LOL

Comment: @PongpiraUpra Even me too :)

Comment: @VishalJohn hahaha

Comment: ok that's funny. But yeah I had this problem also trying to run not from root of the project.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple main methods in your project you can add the following line to your build.sbt file:

```
val projectMainClass = "com.saeed.ApplicationMain"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some(projectMainClass)
```

If you want to specify the class that will be added to the manifest when your application is packaged as a JAR file, add this line to your build.sbt file:

```
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some(projectMainClass)
```

You can also specify main class using run-main command in sbt and activator to run:

```
sbt "run-main com.saeed.ApplicationMain"
```

or

```
activator "run-main com.saeed.ApplicationMain"
```

Answer (score 2):

### There are 4 options

1. you have 1 main class

   - `sbt run` and sbt will find main for you
2. you have 2 or more main classes

   - `sbt run` and sbt will propose to select which one you want to run.

---

```
Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:
[1] a.b.DummyMain1
[2] a.b.DummyMain2
Enter number:
```

---

3. You want to set main class manually.

   ```
   mainClass in run := Some("a.b.DummyMain1")
   ```
4. You could run with main class as parameter

   ```
   sbt runMain a.b.DummyMain1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If the Main class is in a different project then by setting the below command in `build.sbt` would work:

```
addCommandAlias("run", "; project_folder/run")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Resolved it after adding `PlayMinimalJava` plugin in `build.sbt`.

Not sure how it got fixed, if someone can highlight how `PlayMinimalJava` solves it, would be great.

```
enablePlugins(PlayMinimalJava)
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this

```
organization := "org"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
libraryDependencies += guice
enablePlugins(PlayMinimalJava)
```

Log

```
C:\Users\KulwantSingh\repository\pdfdemo>sbt run
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings for project pdfdemo-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\KulwantSingh\repository\pdfdemo\project
[info] Loading settings for project pdfdemo from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to pdfdemo (in build file:/C:/Users/KulwantSingh/repository/pdfdemo/)
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to C:\Users\KulwantSingh\repository\pdfdemo\target\scala-2.13\classes ...
[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

    play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
    play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter

[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev) (no global state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase if someone made a silly mistake like I did.

Check if your project is sbt-multi project.
If it is make sure to provide `sbt moduleName/run` instead of `sbt run`

I keep making this mistake when I switch between multi and single projects.