# Defining a main class in sbt 0.12

Tags: scala, sbt

As I found out, defining a main in `sbt` 0.12 and 0.13 seems different. My `sbt` version is `0.12.2`. I have a few projects in one project. show compile:discovered-main-classes returns the list of the main classes of the project those have it (some of them doesn't have it because they are libraries).

Even in sbt `0.13` there are 2 approaches as you can see here [how to set main class in SBT 0.13 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891708/how-to-set-main-class-in-sbt-0-13-project) (I don't need those ones, though because I use `0.12.2` version)

I didn't specify a main class, therefore whenever I run `run` I get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

How do I specify a main class in a appropriate file in `project` directory of the project?

Comment: It is looks like you run `run` command in project without mail class. Two possible solutions: 1) create a main class; 2) choose a project with main class by command `project <project_name_with_main_class>`

Comment: @Yury, thanks,  this is one of the options, but I want another one. As I said, almost each project has a main class unless that's a library.

Comment: Is this a multi-module build?  Can you show us some of it?  Are you settings in `build.sbt` or in `project/build.scala`?  If they're in `build.sbt` are they scoped by the sub-project? (`mainClass in projectVal := ...`)