# Why does the sbt ~compile command do not recompile on code change?

Tags: scala, sbt

I currently have a problem with recompile on code change with sbt.

I was following the sbt reference '[sbt by example](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html)'
I installed sbt 1.2.8 and followed the instructions:

**Create a minimum sbt build**

```
$ mkdir foo-build
$ cd foo-build
$ touch build.sbt
```

**Start sbt shell**

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\hce\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from E:\learn\Scala\demo\foo-build\project
[info] Loading settings for project foo-build from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to foo-build (in build file:/E:/learn/Scala/demo/foo-build/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-57c501e502d72a00d890
```

**Recompile on code change** (Note the ~ prefix before the compile command)

```
sbt:foo-build> ~compile
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 6, 2019 12:01:24 PM
1. Waiting for source changes in project foo-build... (press enter to interrupt)
```

**Create a source file**

Leave the previous command running. From a different shell or in your file manager create in the project directory the following nested directories: src/main/scala/example. Then, create Hello.scala in the example directory using your favorite editor as follows:

```
package example

object Hello extends App {
  println("Hello")
}
```

This new file should be picked up by the running command. But it is not working on my system.

**Expected Behaviour:**

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/foo-build/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed May 6, 2018 3:53:42 PM
2. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

Here are some Information about my environment

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)

$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\hce\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from E:\learn\Scala\demo\foo-build\project
[info] Loading settings for project foo-build from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to foo-build (in build file:/E:/learn/Scala/demo/foo-build/)
[info] 1.2.8

$ systeminfo.exe | grep '^OS'
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

**What I already tried:**

- reinstall sbt
- try it with windows commad line
- try it mingw64 bash

What am I missing to run the sbt ~compile command correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

The instruction contains an error. 
We are supposed to put the src/main/scala/example directory in the project directory.

> From a different shell or in your file manager **create in the project directory the following nested directories:** src/main/scala/example.

But this leads to the problem described. foo-build/project/ is for build definition code.

If I put the src/main/scala/example directory in the foo-build directory it is working.

I should have executed the **run** command beforehand, which gives the 'No main class detected' error. Which in turn helped to discover, that the directory structure was incorrect by reading the following stackoverflow question: [how to set main class in sbt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891708/how-to-set-main-class-in-sbt-0-13-project) .

My mistake. Sorry for bothering you.